# why XOR of {2,3,4,5} is 0?

Tags: math, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, xor

There are 3 properties in XOR -

1. `N ^ N = 0`
2. `N ^ 0 = N`
3. `A ^ B = B ^ A`

let the array is `{2,3,4,5}` and I am doing XOR of `2 ^ 3 ^ 4 ^ 5` but the answer comes out to 0. why is it 0?

PS: I thought the result would always be zero when there exists a duplicate of every number (`N`) which will make XOR calculation to `0`.
there is an article to use XOR logic to remove duplicate elements in an array because the order of XOR does not matter and two same numbers will result in 0

Edit: based on the answer in the comments, I get it that sometimes the XOR operation can also make the resultant 0, not necessarily that the duplicate must exist to make it zero. sorry, I was a bit confused. thanks for the answers.

Comment: "it should be something else." What makes you think so? What value do you expect? You need to focus your question on the details of the conflict you see. Do you see a conflict of the result "0" and the three rules?

Comment: I suspect that OP needs more help than that simple proof. But if you do insist on answering the question as asked in the title, please do so in an answer post. (I also suspect that OP is not aware of the actual values of the result of the operations.... and is trying to solve this only based on the three rules.)

Comment: @Yunnosch I also suspect as much, but note that if we consider these rules bitwise, then these three rules entirely define XOR. The result of 0^0 and 1^1 is given by rule 1; 1^0 is given by rule 2; 0^1 is given by rule 3 plus rule 2.

Comment: @Stef Bitwise yes. Thinking in bits and binary representations of numbers greater than 1 might however not be within the thinking of somebody asking a math question.

Answer (score 4):

When you evaluate `2 ^ 3 ^ 4 ^ 5` step by step, you get:

- `2 ^ 3` == 1
- `(2 ^ 3) ^ 4` == `(1) ^ 4` == 5
- `((2 ^ 3) ^ 4) ^ 5)` = `((1) ^ 4) ^ 5` == `(5) ^ 5` == 0

In binary, to make the operation more clear:

- 2 ^ 3 becomes: 0010 ^ 0011 == 0001
- 1 ^ 4 becomes: 0001 ^ 0100 == 0101
- 5 ^ 5 becomes: 0101 ^ 0101 == 0000

**Bitwise XOR**: same bits become 0, different bits become 1

Even when you evaluate from right to left:
`2 ^ (3 ^ (4 ^ 5))` == `2 ^ (3 ^ (1))` == `2 ^ (2)` == 0

Comment: Thank you solving my doubt.